# Create a Class that Inherit a Model

Tags: python, django

I have planned in implementing a class that inherits a model then simple display its content. I have found that Django Form Class is implementing it.

```
article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

How can I implement this kind of technique? I wanted to make like this:

```
article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
class_var = MyClass(instance=article)
class_var.show_content()
//then all of the Article details will be displayed

book = Books.objects.get(pk=1)
class_var2 = MyClass(instance=book)
class_var2.show_content()
//then all of the Book details will be displayed
```

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `MyClass` class with has a constructor to accept different type of instances adn `show_content()` method to display the string based on the instance type.

http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html